# Wordpress Error on XAMPP: An unexpected error occurred. Something may be wrong with WordPress.org or this server’s configuration

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, xampp, port

When I try to install a theme or a plugin on Wordpress (on XAMPP), I get this error:

```
An unexpected error occurred. Something may be wrong with WordPress.org or this server’s configuration.
```

I have checked the XAMPP port settings and the ports used by Apache (80, 443) and MySQL (3306) are not being used by anything else:

[XAMPP Netstat](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OU9qe.png)

P.S. MySQL starts successfully.